# Is transit Visa required at London and Dublin?

Tags: uk, canada, transit-visas, ireland, british-airways

I am travelling to Canada with layovers at London and Dublin ( Mumbai - London - Dublin - Canada) with British Airways. I have an Indian passport and Canadian Student Visa. Both the layovers are below 3 hours. Will I be requiring a transit visa to catch the connecting flights from these airports? Ticket is on same booking id with same airlines.

Comment: For clarity, which London airport(s) specifically?

Comment: @henrik I think this is one of the weird corner cases which that question (and the tool) doesn’t answer. I think we had another question on it, and I think possibly the answer is that you need both a UK and Irish transit visa.

Comment: Which airline will you use to fly from Dublin to Canada?

Comment: @Traveller It doesn't matter which London airport. (And with a layover of less than three hours, there's no time to transfer between two London airports, if that was going to be the issue.)

Comment: This might help for the UK https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/740080/UK_Visa_requirements_Sept_2018.pdf

Comment: This is not one of my areas of expertise. Looks like the UK short-term visa is required, but that visa would suffice for Ireland. This is the answer given in the linked question. Ireland does not appear to issue a transit visa to Indians; presumably for a transfer from somewhere _other than the UK_ (e.g., a Schengen state) to Canada an Indian with a Canadian visa would not need an Irish visa at all.

Comment: The airport for London is LHR. I have the British Airways connection from LHR itself to Dublin. And again British Airways from Dublin to Toronto.

Answer (score 1):

**The UK**

[This poster from the Home Office](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/740080/UK_Visa_requirements_Sept_2018.pdf) says that you can transit the UK landside (and that transit to Ireland is always landside) without a visa if you hold a valid Canadian visa and "a valid airline ticket via the UK as part of a reasonable journey TO" Canada.

**Ireland**

According to http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visa-required-transit you will not need an Irish visa if your connection is airside (does not involve passing through Irish border controls). BA can tell you whether this is the case.

If this does not apply to you (i.e. if you have to pass through the border controls to catch your next flight) then you will need a short stay visa.

Comment: Thanks. I am not passing the border controls at both the airports LHR and Dublin. Only a change in terminal at LHR.